# Can't validate date field in json

Tags: android, json

I have some problem.
I have json file with date, where I expect "2017-05-15T19:30:00+01:00".

I want validate date from server using SimpleDateFormat. I use this format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

When I parse expected date all looks good, but if I have invalid date, for example, "15-05-2017T19:30:00+01:00" I also don't have parse exception.

What format I should use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using SimpleDateFormat `Date parse(String text, ParsePosition pos)`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)):

The return value is:

> A Date parsed from the string. In case of error, returns null.

So an exception is not expected for your case, but a null date object.

**Edit:**

I just stumbled on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064925/simpledateformat-and-parsing-parse-doesnt-fail-with-wrong-input-string-date). It says that if you want to make the parsing rigorous you should use `setLenient(false)`.

For example:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    sdf.setLenient(false);

    try {
        date = sdf.parse("15-05-2017T19:30:00+01:00");
        System.out.println("Rigorous date (won't be printed!): "+date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: for example, Fri Nov 07 17:00:00 GMT+03:00 21

Comment: I think I found a solution for this issue in another question.