# Parsing MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss into yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss does not throw parsing exception

Tags: java, date, parsing, timestamp, simpledateformat

Parsing `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`  e.g. `06-26-2017 03:54:26` into `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` does not throw parsing exception. Instead parses the date in incorrect date. How can we handle this in Java?

Below is the code snippet :

```
try {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                      .parse("06-26-2017 03:54:26");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the "incorrect" date?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat.setLenient(false)`

Comment: @nabuchodonossor  - Incorrect date is "Wed Aug 09 03:54:26 IST 13"

Comment: I´m not really firm in java, but I found this question enlighting, because I learned today, that java do some kind of "guessing" if not restricted to strict date handling.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @nabuchodonossor The old and troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and other datetime classes from Java 1.0 and 1.1 show the surprising behaviour you describe. Just avoid them. The modern classes in java.time don’t (or only in very rare cases).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  -SimpleDateFormat.setLenient(false)  worked for me. Thank you for quick response.

Comment: I took this opportunity to write a new and modern answer to the linked original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55021417/5772882).